# Child Theme over write rules

Tags: child-theme

I am currently testing Himalayas theme .

I am working with a child theme of Himalayas for my customization

I am not new to use child theme.. never faced that problem previously

on the parent theme there is `inc/widgets/widgets.php`

I have duplicated it in my child theme, but when I modify it in my child theme the parent theme over write my modification or there is no changes applied at my child them stage.

any idea why the changes on the child them for `inc/widgets/widgets.php` are not working

to test if I have a child theme problem, I did duplicate `page-templates/template-team.php` and when I do changes on `template-team.php` on my child theme, then changes are perfectly applied

any idea?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Child themes only handle template files. The file `widget.php` is loaded by the `functions.php` of the parent then you need to do the same with you new file is the child theme.

And if you want to deregister the sidebars loaded by the parent, you can try that :

```
add_action("widgets_init", function () {

    remove_action("widgets_init", "himalayas_widgets_init");



}, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jack Johanson.. I see the logic and I am trying to play around following your advise but since child is loaded before parent I can't over write the functions there.. thank you again